# How to Get the ToString() from DateTime

Tags: linq

I have tried to get the ToLower() method of string using the below code.

```
 var tolowerMethod = typeof(string).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "ToLower").FirstOrDefault();
```

I am trying to get the ToString() method of DateTime. I have used the below code

```
var formatMethod = typeof(DateTime).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "ToString").ElementAt(1);
```

This is not unique. I have tried something like below but without success.

```
var formatMethod2 = typeof(DateTime).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "ToString").Where(x=>x.GetParameters().Select(t=>t.ParameterType).Equals(typeof(string))).FirstOrDefault();
```

any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: DateTime class have overload of `ToString()` method then how can you get single method using your linq statement.

Comment: which overload of `ToString()` are you after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it have to be linq?
You probably want something like :

```
 var x = typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("ToString", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
```

or

```
 var x = typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("ToString", new Type[] { });
```

or 
 ...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which overload of the ToString( ) method you want:

```
var method = typeof( DateTime ).GetMethods( )
                               .Where ( item => item.Name == "ToString" && 
                                                item.GetParameters( ).Count () == 0 );

// this is the DateTime.Now.ToString( ) method without any parameter
```